# What does "goes" refer to in Luke 22:22?

Tags: luke

> "For the Son of Man goes as it has been determined, but woe to that man by whom he is betrayed!" LUKE 22:22 ESV.

1. Does "goes" refer just to Judas' involvement with what happened to Jesus?
2. Or does "goes" refer not just to Judas' but to all the other human interactions, [e.g. the chief priests and the scribes were seeking how to put him to death Luke 22:2], that led to "him go into heaven"? Acts 1:11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering after your edit, 12 minutes ago: It is the Son of Man who "goes" - Judas played a part in triggering event that would lead to Jesus literally going (to the cross, and hence to his death). But it is not Judas literally going to betray Jesus that is the point of this verse. Jesus is clear that he was "going" (due to betrayal) and even stated that imminent event to all of the disciples after giving them the cup of the new testament in his blood, shed for them (Luke 22:20-21).

The "going" is all about Jesus going "as it was determined". He does something that had been decided upon even before creation started. His time had come to go to the cross.

An interesting reference to the part that Judas, the chief priests and scribes played is in Acts 4:27-28:

> "Indeed Herod and Pontius Pilate met together with the Gentiles and
> the people of Israel in this city to conspire against your holy
> servant Jesus, whom you anointed. They did what your power and will
> had decided beforehand should happen." *(NIV)*

The NIV Study Bible comments regarding verse 28:

> "*decided beforehand*. Not that God had compelled them to act as they
> did, but it was his will to use them and their freely chosen acts to
> accomplish his saving purpose."

There were many more people involved in the outworking of the ancient decree, that the Son of Man would go to his death (Isaiah 52:10 - 53:12 & Psalm 22:1-18) than we are inclined to suppose. Judas played a part, but Jesus had to go to the cross and to his death, the betrayal of Judas being completed in the garden of Gethsemane and the inexorable going to the cross and to death literally happened with Jesus.

Comment: You say "many more people involved". Personally I would include Adam and Eve. +1

Comment: @C. Stroud  Ah, yes! Fair point! Which leads to considering how every other person who has sinned has also been involved in the outworking of this event.

Comment: Answer accepted. Isaiah 52 and Psalm 22 support going "as it has been determined".

Answer (score 3):

#### What does "goes" refer to in Luke 22:22?

To better understand this verse, let's look at the parallel verses:

> The Son of Man goes as it is written of him, but woe to that man by whom the Son of Man is betrayed! It would have been better for that man if he had not been born.–Matthew 26:24 ESV

> For the Son of Man goes as it is written of him, but woe to that man by whom the Son of Man is betrayed! It would have been better for that man if he had not been born.”–Mark 14:21 ESV

Both verses are saying "as it is written of him" is being applied to "the Son of Man". The expression "Son of Man" in the Gospels is most often applied to Jesus Christ himself (see "[Son of Man](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200004183#h=5)" from the *Insight on the Scriptures*). This shows that the word "goes" in Luke 22:22 is referring not to Judas but to Jesus Christ. The words "that man" would be referring to Judas.

But what does the "goes" mean?

[Gill's Exposition of the Entire Bible](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/gill/luke/22.htm) has the following commentary:

> And truly the son of man goeth,.... That is, dies, which is going the way of all the earth, [Joshua 23:14](https://biblehub.com/joshua/23-14.htm)

Comment: re:Luke 22:22 Gill's Ex. says "the manner and the means by which it was brought about were  all predetermined by God". So does that go back to Adam's sin or is there some cut off point, where the manner and means only refer to the immediate circumstances of the cross?

Comment: @C.Stroud That portion of Gill's is talking about "as it was determined" just as the verses in Matthew and Mark that I quoted are referring to the prophecies in the Bible about the death of the Messiah.

Answer (score 2):

> "For the Son of Man **goes** as it has been determined, but woe to that man by whom he is betrayed!" LUKE 22:22 ESV.

will go
πορεύεται (poreuetai)
Verb - Present Indicative Middle or Passive - 3rd Person Singular
Strong's 4198: To travel, journey, go, die.

G4198 appears 154 times.
Thayer's Greek Lexicon:

> a. properly: τήν ὁδόν μου, to pursue the **journey** on which one has entered, continue one's journey (A. V. go on one's way)
>
> b. By a Hebraism, metaphorically, α. to **depart from life**

By extension, it means to go on a journey to ones' death. This interpretation is consistent with the context: "it has been determined", i.e., this journey to death was planned in detail beforehand. It was a step-by-step journey.

Does "goes" refer not just to Judas' but to all the other human interactions, [e.g. the chief priests and the scribes were seeking how to put him to death Luke 22:2], that led to "him go into heaven"? Acts 1:11.

This linear journey/path had a fixed destination.
I'd say that it includes all the events from then onward that lead to Jesus' death on the cross when he uttered "it is finished."

Answer (score 1):

The operative verb here is πορεύομαι (poreuomai) is occurs more than 150 times in the NT.  According to BDAG it has three basic meanings:

1. **to move over an area generally with a point of departure or destination specified, *go, proceed, travel***, eg, Matt 25:41, Luke 4:42, etc
2. **to conduct oneself, *live, walk***, eg, 1 Peter 4:3, Luke 1:6, etc
3. **go to one's death**, Luke 22:22, 33

The third of these meanings is the salient one here.  Thus, the CEV translates Luke 22:22 as:

> The Son of Man will die in the way that has been decided for him, but
> it will be terrible for the one who betrays him!"

Similarly, the GNT has this:

> The Son of Man will die as God has decided, but how terrible for that
> man who betrays him!"

Similarly, GOD'S WORD® Translation:

> The Son of Man is going to die the way it has been planned for him.
> But how horrible it will be for that person who betrays him."

Even the conservative commentator, Matthew Henry reaches a similar conclusion:

> 22:21-38 How unbecoming is the worldly ambition of being the greatest,
> to the character of a follower of Jesus, who took upon him the form of
> a servant, and humbled himself to the death of the cross!

**Further Note**

It is instructive that the verb πορεύομαι (poreuomai) in Luke 22:22 is in the middle or voice - Jesus voluntarily laid down His life for the salvation of the world

> John 10:14-18 - I am the good shepherd. I know My sheep and My sheep
> know Me ... And I lay down My life for the sheep. ... The reason the
> Father loves Me is that I lay down My life in order to take it up
> again. No one takes it from Me, but I lay it down of My own accord. I
> have authority to lay it down and authority to take it up again....”